# Cursor freezes with Asus and Ubuntu

Tags: touchpad, asus, 19.04, cursor

I bought an ASUS FX504. I installed ubuntu 19.0.4 in it. Unfortunately the cursor is freezing quite often. As I develop apps, its frustrating when I get this situation. Is there any specific trackpad drivers or something that I could do to fix this issue?

Comment: Does that work fine on Windows or other Linux distribution?
Possibly this is touchpad hardware issue

Comment: You can check, if this is software issue (try other OS for your laptop).
If it is software, here are some things you can try to fix or improve you working with touchpad experience:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection

Comment: @VitaliiDiravka Turns out that it is a failure model just like most other ASUS systems that are manufactured with defects